# Set active collection by selected object Blender 2.83

Tags: collections

I cant find this simple function in blender:

Press button  - set active collection by select object

*Like in 3ds max: set active layer by object*[image]

Comment: An object can be placed under several collections simultaneously. Which one gets set active?

Comment: I updated the post
I think that can be named as "the lowest in the hierarchy collection"

For this situation a need the "Daughter" Collection

Comment: That object is till only under one collection "*Son*" despite it being a sub-collection. Basically what I'm getting at is that it is not really possible to determine a single collection from an object.

Comment: But if you will select "select grouped" - "Collection" it will worked and sometimes it requests to determine collection that you need, if they more than one. So i guees it's possible. 
And this is a generic function in programs like that, i mean with some sort of layers

Answer (score 0):

With <kbd>J</kbd> key in Outliner or in View in Object Mode it switch collection to active by selected object.
It can't be implemented as always on, because you can't change active collection then, it will be always related to active object which in some cases problems.

````
    # ##### BEGIN GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####
    #
    #  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
    #  modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
    #  as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
    #  of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
    #
    #  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    #  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    #  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    #  GNU General Public License for more details.
    #
    #  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    #  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
    #  Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
    #
    # ##### END GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####
    
    import bpy
    bl_info = {
        "name": "Switch Active Collection",
        "location": "3D View / Outliner, (Hotkey J)",
        "version": (0, 1, 0),
        "blender": (2, 90, 0),
        "description": "Switching active Collection to active Object selected",
        "author": "APEC",
        "category": "Object",
    }
    
    #Recursivly transverse layer_collection for a particular name
    def recurLayerCollection(layerColl, collName):
        found = None
        if (layerColl.name == collName):
            return layerColl
        for layer in layerColl.children:
            found = recurLayerCollection(layer, collName)
            if found:
                return found
    
    class OUTLINER_OT_switch_collection(bpy.types.Operator):
        bl_idname = "outliner.switch_collection"
        bl_label = "Switch Collection"
        bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    
        @classmethod
        def poll(self, context):
            ar = context.screen.areas
            __class__.area = next(
                (a for a in ar if a.type == 'OUTLINER'), None)
            return __class__.area
    
        def execute(self, context):
            obj = bpy.context.object
            ucol = obj.users_collection
    
            #Switching active Collection to active Object selected
            for i in ucol:
                layer_collection = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection
                layerColl = recurLayerCollection(layer_collection, i.name)
                bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = layerColl
            return {'FINISHED'}
    
    
    addon_keymaps = []
    
    
    def register():
        bpy.utils.register_class(OUTLINER_OT_switch_collection)
        wm = bpy.context.window_manager
        kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps
        km = kc.get("Object Mode")
        if not km:
            km = kc.new("Object Mode")
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new("outliner.switch_collection", "J", "PRESS")
        addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))
    
        km = kc.get("Outliner")
        if not km:
            km = kc.new("Outliner", space_type="OUTLINER")
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new("outliner.switch_collection", "J", "PRESS")
        addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))
    
    
    def unregister():
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(OUTLINER_OT_switch_collection)
    
        for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
            km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
        addon_keymaps.clear()
```
````